# How can I match a hyphen (-) and hash (#) sign in awk?

Tags: bash, awk

I'm trying to match a `hyphen` and a `hash sign` in a while loop in `awk`. My current setup is:

```
awk 'BEGIN { while ($1==# && $2==-) { #do stuff} }'
```

This obviously results in a syntax error on the hash sign. I've tried escaping it in all kinds of ways, but this either results in a syntax error, or a "backslash not last character on line" error.

So: How can I match the `hash sign` and `hyphen` in an `awk` expression?

Comment: have you tried between double quotes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `while` in a `BEGIN` is probably not what you want, unless `#do stuff` includes a `next` or some other statement to get to the next line of input.  To answer your specific question, I'll assume you want to check each line of input.  I am using `echo -e 'foo bar skip\n# - printme'` to provide two lines of input: `foo bar skip` and `# - printme`, and I am using `print $3` in place of `#do stuff`.

```
echo -e 'foo bar skip\n# - printme' | awk '($1=="#" && $2=="-") { print $3 }'
                                              # ^ ^        ^ ^ double quotes
```

prints `printme`, as it should.  You can also do that with regular expressions:

```
 echo -e 'foo bar skip\n# - printme' | awk '($1~/^#$/ && $2~/^-$/) { print $3} '
                                             # ^^   ^      ^^   ^ regex match
```

The `~` is the regex match operator, and the `//` delimit the regex.  **Edit** The `^` and `$` are so the regex matches the whole field, and doesn't succeed if, e.g., `$1` merely *contains* a hyphen.

Tested on gawk 4.1.3 on cygwin.

Comment: This is indeed functioning as intended, thank you kindly. I must have skipped over the exact use of `BEGIN` while reading, I'm completely new to `awk`. Thank you for the complete and very educational answer.

Comment: @Timmiej93 awk is a lot of fun - I wish you much success!  Yes, BEGIN happens only once, before the first line of input is read.

Comment: @Timmiej93 when you immediately accept the first answer you get, that's usually the only answer you get even if there's better answers possible. It's usually a good idea to give it a few hours after posting a question before accepting an answer so you get to choose between several answers instead of getting just 1 answer. Also edit your question to include a [mcve] with concise, testable sample input and expected output to ensure you get a good solution to your problem rather than help implementing what may be a bad solution to your problem.